# RECORD COUNT in SQL with an ORDER BY, until a specific value is found in a column

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get a row count from a record set.

What I would like is to count the number of rows in the record-set, grouped by a common value in a column named `member_location`, ordered by a column named `reputation_total_points` in descending order, until the parser reaches a result with a specific value in the `ID` column.

For example, if the query was using **`member_location`= 10**, and **`id`= 2**, the final correct count result will be **3** by using the information below. Below is a sample of the db entries:

```
Columns: id | reputation_total_points | member_location

2 | 32 | 10

3 | 35 | 7

4 | 40 | 10

5 | 15 | 5

6 | 10 | 10

7 | 65 | 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should work as expected:

```
SELECT rn
FROM
 (
   SELECT id
      ,ROW_NUMBER() -- assign a sequence based on descending order
       OVER (ORDER BY reputation_total_points DESC) AS rn
   FROM tab
   WHERE member_location = 10
 ) AS dt
WHERE id = 2 -- find the matching id
```

In fact this seems like you want to rank your members:

```
SELECT id
    ,RANK() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY member_location
          ORDER BY reputation_total_points DESC) AS rnk
FROM tab
```

Comment: @jondee: glad it worked. A final remark, if there are multiple rows with the same `reputation_total_points` as `id 2` you probably might want to switch to `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your where works with both id and member_location, as the id = 2 will only bring back one row. However if you're just after the occurences where member_location = 10 then something like the below should work:

```
SELECT 
    member_location, 
    COUNT(member_location) AS [Total]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY member_location
```

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, but I can't get why do you need grouping.

```sql
DECLARE @id int = 2

SELECT member_location, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM <table_name>
WHERE reputation_total_points >= (SELECT reputation_total_points FROM <table_name> WHERE id = @id) 
  AND id <> @id
GROUP BY member_location
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to group by `member_location`, but exclude a specific id. In this case, what you want is:

```
SELECT member_location, count(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE id <> 2
GROUP BY member_location
```

For your input, this would return:

```
member_location    count(*)
5                  1
7                  1
10                 3
```